# SDOC extract compound field values

Tags: document

Is there a way to extract the values from a compound field, such as the 'mailing address' on the contact record?
[image]

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce? Can you clarify and elaborate as what and where are you trying to extract this information? If it's in Salesforce, then yes you can extract it from [Address compound field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm).

Comment: Yes it's for a S-DOC template.  But i think i should just use the column names (mailing city, mailing country) instead of trying to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what S-Docs is, but the address fields on Contact can be retrieved thus:

Contact.MailingStreet

Contact.MailingCity

Contact.MailingState

Contact.MailingPostalCode

Contact.MailingCountry

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reference them as you would any other object property:

```
String city = someRecord.MailingAddress.City;
```

See the [Address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_Address.htm) object for more information.

Comment: Thanks but i'm doing this within a S-DOCS template.  {{!AO_Application__c.AO_Contact__r.MailingAddress.City}} thorws an error when it's creating the document.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, no need to reinvent the wheel.  I'll just use the 'Mailing...' column names on the contact record.

Answer (score 0):

Put something like this in your S-Doc template.

```
<!--{{!
<callable>
<class>InvoiceSDocController</class>
<action>getAddress</action>
<args>{ "orderSummaryId" : "{{!OrderSummary.id}}"}</args>
</callable>
}}-->
{{!BillingAddress_City}}  {{!BillingAddress_Country}} 
{{!BillingAddress_PostalCode}}
```

And create an Apex class that looks something like this

```
global class InvoiceSDocController implements Callable {
    public Object call(String action, Map<String, Object> args) {
      switch on action {
        when 'getAddress' {
          return this.getAddress((String) args.get('orderSummaryId'));
        }
        when else {
          throw new ExtensionMalformedCallException('Method not implemented');
        }
      }
    }
    public class ExtensionMalformedCallException extends Exception {
    }
    public Map<String, String> getAddress(String orderSummaryId) {
      System.Address address = [
        SELECT billingAddress
        FROM OrderSummary
        WHERE Id = :orderSummaryId
      ]
      .billingAddress; // Base Object Record
      Map<String, String> ret = new Map<String, String>();
      ret.put('BillingAddress_City', address.city);
      ret.put('BillingAddress_Country', address.country);
      ret.put('BillingAddress_PostalCode', address.postalcode);
      return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. this is new?  pretty neat.